# Why do we have a symbol for root of -1, but none for divide by zero?

Tags: arithmetic

Even though there is no real answer to the equation `√-1`, we give it the symbol [***i***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_number).

What is the reason that there is a symbol for `√-1`, but no symbol for dividing by zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be many possible answers to your question.

1. $\sqrt{-1}$ has a root symbol and writing it again and again will be quite boring as well as confusing because when writing on paper over a long period then it may be possible that a variable falls in the that root sign (by mistake).
2. We have branch of complex numbers and we use Re-Im graph in which imaginary axis is plotted with multiple of $\sqrt{-1}$ so we use i to denote $\sqrt{-1}$.
3. For ${\frac{a}{0}}=b,$ a not equal to 0.

$\implies b.0=a $

Now for which b the equation is valid, and you will find that there exist no value of b that satisfies the above equation.

So giving a symbol to  this expression is useless.

What is the value of $b^{2}$? but $i^{2}=-1$

1. For what $\infty$   is defined? It is for b

Now you tell what will be $b^{2}$ it will not be $\infty$.